# Having a default expression when creating a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know is there any ways whereby i can count on the number of late for different column lengthe.Below is the sql to create i am using

```
    CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE
    (
        Student_ID  number (5),
        StudentName VARCHAR2 (30),y
        “1/2/2015” VARCHAR2 (10),
        “2/2/2015” VARCHAR2 (10),
        “3/2/2015” VARCHAR2 (10),
        Late AS // not sure how to count nmber of late,
        Absent AS // not sure how to count number of absent
        Present AS // not sure how to count number of present
    );
```

The table will be as below, the dates is not fixed means like there will be sometimes more dates or few dates
[image]

Comment: A table with dates as column names... Re-design!

Comment: you shouldn't have dates as column names, you should create a child table to store the dates. You can then create a trigger on row insert or update on the child table, to update the attendance.late, attendance.absent, and attendance.present

Comment: thanks for the reply, can i know why dates cant be used as column names?

Comment: @jarlh is right, this table structure will only give you a world of hurt. Consider having one column DAY_ATTENDED DATE, and ATTENDANCE_ID NUMBER(1) where attendance_id is a primary key in another table with values of 1,2,3 representing Late, Absent, Present

Comment: Don't update the late/absent/present columns. Those shouldn't exist at all. Use @kevinsky's suggestion and then calculate the other numbers when you need them.

Comment: i am still confuse, it basically like this is for taking students attendance like if there is 40 students , there will will be a total of 40 student_id and then based on the date which the present, a present will be marked based on the date, the at end, it will calculated like latte for a particular students how many tiems, present for a particular students how many  times.

Comment: thanks, can i know if it use like @kevinsky idea, can i generate as shown in the image.

Comment: Adn what will you do on 4/2/2015, add another column?  And on 5/2/2015? And...

Comment: i will like create a table for each semester. yup the date continues. I have another idea as like @kevinsky but i am not sure like for each date i want to display those students that is present, absent and late., not only those that are present and late. Is it possible sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a more normalized table structure. Much more could be done:
- add a column in STUDENT to show if the student is currently attending
- add a package to insert, update, delete data

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(ID NUMBER(9),
STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(500), 
CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT PRIMARY KEY(ID));
--------
CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE_TYPE
(ID NUMBER(9),
AT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(250),
CONSTRAINT PK_ATTENDANCE_TYPE PRIMARY KEY(ID))
------------------------
CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE(
ID NUMBER(9),
STUDENT_ID NUMBER(9),
ATTENDANCE_DAY DATE,
ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID NUMBER(9),
CONSTRAINT PK_ATTENDANCE PRIMARY KEY(ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ATTENDANCE_TYPE
FOREIGN KEY (ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ATTENDANCE_TYPE(ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT
FOREIGN KEY (STUDENT_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(ID));

--this gets the number of students late in Jan, Feb and March 1st this year
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM student s JOIN attendance att
ON s.ID = att.student_id
WHERE att.attendance_type_id = 2
AND att.attendance_day BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01-MAR-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Comment: thanks alot, now i getting an idea on this, this is really cool. Thanks alot alot..